# std::unordered_map - Implicit instantiation of undefined template?

Tags: c++, templates, hashmap, unordered-map

I've done lots of languages, but I'm new to C++ and I'm completely stumped about how to initialize class instances. The following code gets an error at

```
class MyClass
{
   public:

    //Hash map variable

    //ERROR BELOW
    std::unordered_map<int, float, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int>> myUnorderedMap;

}
```

I think I'm filling in the template incorrectly. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Did you `#include <unordered_map>`? Also, just simple `std::unordered_map<int, float> myUnorderedMap;` should be sufficient. The other three parameters have reasonable defaults.

Comment: That was it, the two-argument template wasn't popping up in autofill since I wasn't including <unordered_map>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the library header:

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

and you don't need to put default types in your declaration:

```
std::unordered_map<int, float> myUnorderedMap;
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought including the std library would be enough. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Sequence You're welcome... the standard library is composed of 100s of headers!

Comment: Semicolon is useless to include headers, `#include <unordered_map>` works as expected.